# VS code says answer is not a member of None, inline keyboard doesn't do anything

Tags: python, python-3.x, async-await, python-asyncio, aiogram

[image]

I tried reloading, trying to not use .message, but this does nothing (aiogram 3.0), it seems like something is bugged.

This is the code for inline keyboard:

```py
me =InlineKeyboardMarkup(inline_keyboard=[
    [InlineKeyboardButton(text='yes', callback_data='yes')],
    [InlineKeyboardButton(text='no', callback_data='no')]
])
```

CallbackQuery is imported from `aiogram.types`.

Comment: The docs say that `message` is optional, its type is `Message | None`. You forgot to check whether it's `None`, so in case it _is_ `None` you currently would attempt to access `None.answer` which is not possible, hence the error.